# Query Task Pagination

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

In the 10.3 REST API they introduced:

Supports pagination in a query layer. Use resultOffset and resultRecordCountparameters to page through a query result.

I don't see any options to take advantage of these features in the ArcGIS .NET Runtime SDK.

Am I missing it? Is it a planned feature? Is there way I could add this functionality?